# vbs taskkill by name

Tags: vbscript, taskkill

I'am trying to find how to close a process using it's title.

I found the command:

```
taskkill /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq the_title_of_the_windows"
```

and it works great.

When I try:

```
oShell.Run "taskkill /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq the_title_of_the_windows"", , True
```

I get an error and it won't compile.

Any idea on how to use th symbole " in this line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use double quotation marks inside another pair of double quotation marks, you need to use `""` instead of just `"`, because if you use one quotation mark `"` it will be considered the end of text between the first and the second quotation marks

So, your code should look like this:

```
oShell.Run "taskkill /fi ""WINDOWTITLE eq the_title_of_the_windows""", , True
```

The following example will terminate all processes with window title (Calculator):

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "taskkill /fi ""WINDOWTITLE eq Calculator""", , True
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can try below code:
This code will pick the task from Task manager and close the process.
Copy pasted the code in ".vbs" File and use call KillAll("your task name.exe")

```
Function KillAll(ProcessName)
    Dim objWMIService, colProcess
    Dim strComputer, strList, p
    Dim i :i= 0 
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
    Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name like '" & ProcessName & "'")
    For Each p in colProcess
        p.Terminate     
    i = i+1        
    Next
    MsgBox("Total Instance :: " &i& " of "&ProcessName&" is killed")
End Function

call KillAll("MicrosoftEdge.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Run` to execute the command line you will find ugly dos windows popup in the screen to avoid that use one of two ways:

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Exec "taskkill /fi ""WINDOWTITLE eq Calculator"""
```

OR

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "taskkill /fi ""WINDOWTITLE eq Calculator""",0,False
```